# How does AngularJS talk with server side Java EE code?

Tags: angularjs

Just found AngularJS and would like to try out a simple example CRUD app on GAE.

Idea is to save the records on the mysql db.

In a traditional webapp, my layering would have been `client->controller->service->dao->db`.

Any reference to a simple tutorial or article would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to build the server side of the application as a REST server, serve the AngularJS application as a static page, and then have the AngularJS application make calls to the server with the `$http` service.

I'm not particularly familiar with Google App Engine, but there appear to be some useful resources for REST:

- http://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server/
- http://code.google.com/p/gae-json-rest/
- http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2727-deploy-java-restful-application-on-the-google-app-engine/